# Neukirch, Lemma 2.9 Doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Lemma (cf. Neukirch, I.2.9).** Write $d$ for the discriminant of $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$. Then $d\mathcal{O}_L \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n$.

*Proof:* If $\alpha = c_1 \alpha_1 + \cdots + c_n \alpha_n \in \mathcal{O}_L$, with coefficients $c_i$ in $K$, then the $c_i$ are a solution of the system of linear equations
$$\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha) = \sum_j \operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha_j)c_j,$$
and as $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i \alpha) \in \mathcal{O}_K$, **they are given as the quotient of an element of $\mathcal{O}_K$ by the determinant $\det \operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i \alpha_j) = d$**. Therefore the $dc_j$ live in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and the desired result follows.

I am trying to understand the bolded statement. Is it simply true because, upon solving the linear system of equations for $c_j$, we would get that $c_j = \frac{d_j}{d}$, where $d_j$ live in $A$? If so, how do we get this? And why does this imply $dc_j$ is in $\mathcal{O}_K$? Thank you!

Comment: Remember $\operatorname{adj}(A)A=\det(A)I$ for any square matrix $A$ over a ring, and the construction of the adjugate matrix $\operatorname{adj}(A)$.

Comment: If you have understood the rest then everything else follows from Cramer's rule